# Minimize API calls to cloud storage

Tags: spring-boot, cloudinary

I am working on a personal project like social media (Reddit, Instagram) where we can upload image or short videos and I am using cloud storage to upload images and videos ( Cloudinary ) and I am storing the URL in DB.

I am facing an issue while updating the post I want to delete images from the cloud and again I have to upload the new file (image/video) in Cloud storage and update the URL in the DB.
So a total of 3 network calls is required while performing the update operation which is very expensive and I want to minimize it.

My Solution: I am thinking of not performing the delete operation which will save a network call but it will waste my storage as those images/videos won't be required.

**I am looking for a better solution where I can save the storage in the cloud as well as save a network call.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you can do an upload which overwrites the existing asset from the post by specifying the public_id of the asset. This way you do not use extra storage in your account. See https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520852-I-ve-replaced-an-existing-image-with-a-new-one-but-my-website-still-shows-the-old-one-Why-is-that-